# jquery libs in reactjs loads slower

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am using react and jquery steps, I have this in my render method

```
<div refs="checkboxContainer" id='wizard-1'>
<h1>First Step</h1>
<div>
<LoremIpsum query='5s' />
</div>
<h1>Second Step</h1>
<div><LoremIpsum query='5s' /></div>
</div>
```

and I have this in `componentDidMount`

```
$('#wizard-1').steps({
    autoFocus: true
})
```

the problem is that the page is rendered like this at the first for seconds

[image]

then it renders as I want like this

[image]

I know that this is happening because it renders first then the jquery steps works after the component is rendered in componentDidMount,
I don't want this to happen, I want it to render from the beginning as the second picture.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading jQuery from remote source ? that can happen for many reasons but if you load something from external source and it take sometime to load or something block loading in the middle that will probably happen, you can even notice that for some websites when styles load after sometime and website appear messy, i would say you can hide the divs and show them after apply the steps or just before applying the steps.